Trying to prove that $\exists x \forall y (Rxy \to Fa) \vdash \exists x \forall y Rxy \to Fa$
I can't work out a formal deduction for $$\exists x \forall y(Rxy \to Fa) \vdash (\exists x \forall y Rxy) \to Fa,$$ and can't find any counter-model either.

There is no formal proof because it is not valid.
Counterexample:
Consider a world with two objects $a$ and $b$. Suppose we have $Rba$ and $Rbb$ but neither $Raa$ nor $Rab$. Also we do not have $Fa$.

To prove $$∃x∀y(Rxy→Fa)⊢(∃x∀yRxy)→Fa$$

$∃x∀y(Rxy→Fa)$ - Premise

$∃x∀yRxy$ - Assumption for implication introduction

$c$ - name a constant for $∃x∀y(Rxy→Fa)$ (line 1)
3a. $∀y(Rcy→Fa)$ - from line 1, existential elimination

$d$ - name a constant for $∃x∀yRxy$ (line 2)
4a. $∀yRdy$ - from line 2, existential elimination

$Rcd$ - from line 4a, universal elimination

$Rcd→Fa$ - from line 3a, universal elimination

$Fa$ - from lines 5 and 6, Modus Ponens

$(∃x∀yRxy)→Fa$ - implication introduction, discharging assumption in line 2
as required.



thanks this makes sense, but the difficulty I faced was in trying to find a formal deduction for this.

What proof system are you trying to use to make this proof? I was taught Suppes-Lemmon proofs, and it should be straightforward to express this as one. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction

@TomDietterich I'm only taught Fitch-style proofs in the course I'm attending

I'm unfamiliar with Fitch-style, but maybe something like this is similar? I've edited my post.

Step 5 is incorrect. You cannot infer $Rcd$ from $\forall y \ Rdy$
